# VMware - Deploy from Template - VM should be powered off

Tags: ansible, vmware, automated-deployment

Actually i am using Ansible to automate the deployment process off my VMs. I am able to deploy a VM with Ansible in my ESX Environment, this VM will be depolyed from a Template.

So now i need to make sure, that the VM is powered off, when it's deployed.
When i try to add the command:

```
state: poweredoff
```

in Ansible , in my Playbook, then i get an Error. So I think i need to adjust this setting maybe in the VMX File of the VMware template?

But where can i find a specific parameter?

I Hope you guy's can maybe help me!

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling, please. From the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html): `state: powered_off`

Comment: Already did this.
Still getting the error 
"fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "parameters are mutually exclusive: ['state'                          , 'from_template']"}"

// Dont know why i am getting this... any idea?

Comment: This is how `vsphere_guest` works – you can't define states when cloning.

Comment: Yeah i know, thats why i'm asking if there is any possibility to adjust the stting IN the VMX file of VMware OR in the Playbook ?
When i take a look into the module list, i see that there is a setting "state: poweredon" ?
why can't i set it to powered_off?